# Save .vtk voxelized file in Python

Tags: python, vtk

I have a 3D matrix data from a txt file representing voxels.
I already represented them in vtk as a structured grid:

```
grid = vtk.vtkExplicitStructuredGrid()
```

Everything working fine. Adding color functions, actors, renderer, window...
But now I want to save it as a .vtk file to read it with other applications and I don't know how.
I tried:

```
exporter = vtk.vtkVRMLExporter()
exporter.SetRenderWindow(window)
exporter.SetFileName("sample.vtk")
exporter.Write()
exporter.Update()
```

But it creates a file almost empty, just with metadata and not voxels data.
I tried change it for: vtkVTKExporter and didn't work too.

I also tried to use other functions calling the "grid" but didn't even created the file:

```
vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter
vtkXMLPolyDataWriter
vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter
```

And finally I tried to use:

```
writer = vtk.vtkStructuredPointsWriter()
windowto_image_filter = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
windowto_image_filter.SetInput(window)
windowto_image_filter.SetScale(1)  # image quality
windowto_image_filter.SetInputBufferTypeToRGBA()
writer.SetFileName('sample2.vtk')
writer.SetInputConnection(windowto_image_filter.GetOutputPort())
writer.Write()
```

But leads to an error.

Is there a way to save it as a .vtk file in binary with all the represented information? And also, is there a way to save the image in the vtk window created as a .jpg or .png like a screenshot.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to save the entire scene (i.e. every actors with their current coloration and lights) or just your grid with its data ?
Also, [`vtkExplicitStructuredGrid`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkExplicitStructuredGrid.html#details) is quite exotic, do you really need this one ? (`vtkStructuredGrid` or `vtkUnstructuredGrid` are more popular)

Comment: Just the grid with data.
And I also did at first `vtkStructuredGrid ` but for some problem reading it I changed to `vtkExplicitStructuredGrid` but supose does not change the way is saved as an vtk object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving grid with data: use a writer (exporter are mean to save "what is visible now", and not the underlying data).

With `vtkStructuredGrid`, use `vtkXMLStructureGridWriter` to have a `.vts` file, or `vtkDataSetWriter` to produce legacy `.vtk` file.
Then call `writer.SetInputData(grid)`

To save screenshot, you can use `vtkPNGWriter` on the output of your `vtkWindowToImageFilter`,
as describe in this [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Utilities/Screenshot/)